# regular expression javascript numbers and letters

Tags: javascript, regex, formatting

I can't for the life of me seem to figure out how to set a regular expression of an element with the formatting.

```
1d 5h 6m 12s
```

And also allow it to have any variation of those such as

```
1d 

1d 1h

1d 1h 1m 

1d 1s

6m 12s 

etc...
```

Is it possible with regular expressions to do that tyle of formatting?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Regular expressions don't have much to do with formatting.

Comment: Are you trying to parse that type of value for valid timespans?  Or trying to convert it to something?  What's the goal.

Comment: Starting point for an answer: "^(\d+d)? ?(\d+h)? ?(\d+m)? ?(\d+s)? ?". Let us know why this isn't good enough.

Comment: well maybe regualr expressions isn't the way to go, but what i need is when a user is typing into an input field and i run validation on that field i need it to only include any combination of the days,hours,minutes and seconds formatted as a number and then their letter like 5m 1s which would be 5 minutes 1 seconds

Comment: before determining whether you should use regular expressions, you need to set out some well-defined criteria for passing and failing. What sorts of patterns do you want to match, and almost *more* importantly, what types of patterns do you *not* want to match?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you need it to be order,

```
if (/^\s*(?:(?:[1-9]\d*|0)d\s+)?(?:(?:1?\d|2[0-3])h\s+)?(?:[1-5]?\dm\s+)?(?:[1-5]?\ds)?\s*$/.test(str))
{
    // success
}
```

Here's a quick breakdown:

1. The `^` and `$` are known as *anchors*. They match the beginning and end of a string, so you're matching the entire string, not only a part, *e.g.* `hello, world! 1d 5h 6m 12s` would pass otherwise.
2. The `\s*` and `\s+` match zero or more, and one or more, whitespace characters.
3. The `(?:[1-9]\d*|0)` matches an arbitrary number of digits but not one that start with zero, unless it's exactly zero.
4. The `(?:1?\d|2[0-3])` matches the digits between 0 and 23, inclusive.
5. The `[1-5]?\d` matches the digits between 0 and 59, inclusive.
6. The `(?: ... )` are known as *non-capturing groups*. They're like parentheses (for grouping) except that plain ol' parentheses *capture*, and we don't need that here.
7. The `?` means the preceding entity is optional.

Comment: Note this will match on newlines and tabs.

Comment: Use `test()` not `match()` if you want only a boolean result

Comment: But this fails on the example inputs like "1d 1h". The problem is the `\s+` outside of the groups.

Answer (score 0):

To give you a starting point:

```
(\d+d){0,1} //days - not checking for a max

(((([0-1]){0,1}\d)|(2[0-4]))h){0,1} // 24 hours

(((([0-5]){0,1}[0-9])|(60))m){0,1} //60 minutes

(((([0-5]){0,1}[0-9])|(60))s){0,1} //60 seconds
```

Then put them all together (in this case not worrying about amount of whitespace)

```
(\d+d){0,1}[ ]*(((([0-1]){0,1}\d)|(2[0-4]))h){0,1}[ ]*(((([0-5]){0,1}[0-9])|(60))m){0,1}[ ]*(((([0-5]){0,1}[0-9])|(60))s){0,1}[ ]*
```

Including @nhahtdh 's improved version of the above from the comments. Thanks!

```
((\d+)d)? *(([01]?\d|2[0-4])h)? *(([0-5]?\d|60)m)? *(([0-5]?\d|60)s)? *
```

Comment: I see one the is superfluous (fixed). I think the rest are required for the approach that I took. I was aiming for regex-newbie readable. May have failed :)

Comment: `((\d+)d)? *(([01]?\d|2[0-4])h)? *(([0-5]?\d|60)m)? *(([0-5]?\d|60)s)? *` - simplified from your regex. Not as "regex-newbie-friendly" (no sarcasm intended) as yours.

Comment: @nhahtdh I intended the sarcasm :) - I tend to include the capturing groups to show explicitly (in a code-like style) where the breaks for the OR will happen. I actually don't know that it helps anyone and should just stop doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
function parse(s) {
 y = s.match(/(?:(\d+)d\s*)?(?:(\d+)h\s*)?(?:(\d+)m\s*)?(?:(\d+)s)?/);
 console.log(y);
 return y;
}
```

Here's how it works:

- `(\d+)d\s*` matches some digits followed by a `d`, followed by optional whitespace
- wrapping it in `(?:...)?`, like `(?:(\d+)d\s*)?` makes the above optional. The `?:` causes the new set of parentheses to not be a capturing group.
- repeat for h, m and s and you're done.